# Способы добавления записей в Access

Tags: c#, ado.net

Для добавления записей в Access использую код:

```
string connStringAcc = string.Format("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0}", textBox2.Text); // textBox2.Text - путь к базе
            using (OleDbConnection connAcc = new OleDbConnection(connStringAcc))
            {
                connAcc.Open();
                OleDbCommand command1 = new OleDbCommand
                    ("INSERT INTO " + textBox10.Text + // ТАБЛИЦА
                    "(" + textBox15.Text + // ПОЛЯ
                    ") VALUES"
                    + "('"
                    +
                      pol_1 + "', '" + pol_2
                    +
                    "')",
                    connAcc); 
                    command1.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Есть другие способы добавления записей в Access?

Comment: Не знаю, чем Вас не устроил подход с `OleDbConnection`, но если все вынести в отдельные методы и красиво оформить, то выглядит это не так уж и плохо. Возможно Вас заинтересует следующая страница: [Практическое руководство. Вставка новых записей в базу данных](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms233812.aspx)

Comment: @Denis Bubnov Пока осваиваю, поэтому может вопрос не логичный... Но хочу посмотреть как будет работать база с максимальным количеством записей.. Для этого хочу записать ~500 000 записей.. Через описанный мной код, записи добавляются долго. Поэтому и спрашиваю: может другие способы есть

Comment: для быстрой записи большого количества записей нужно использовать что-то на подобии `Bulk Insert`

Comment: @DenisBubnov, в Access нету Bulk.

Comment: @iluxa1810, так я не писал, что он есть, писал же *что-то на подобии `Bulk Insert`*

Answer (score 1):

Имеется достаточно неплохое руководство на MSDN: [Практическое руководство. Вставка новых записей в базу данных](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms233812.aspx), в котором есть следующие пункты:

**Вставка новых записей с помощью адаптеров таблиц**

В этом пункте все достаточно просто. Есть два подхода для вставки данных в нужную таблицу `DataTable` в наборе данных, с помощью `TableAdapter.Update` и  `TableAdapter.Insert`. Для этого понадобится экземпляр [DataTable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.data.datatable.aspx), который будет использоваться в качестве адаптера таблиц.

*Для вставки новых записей в базу данных с помощью метода TableAdapter.Update:*

1. Добавьте новые записи в нужные таблицы `DataTable` путем создания
   новых строк `DataRow` и добавления их к коллекции `Rows`. Дополнительные
   сведения см. в разделе Практическое руководство. Добавление строк в
   объект `DataTable`.
2. После добавления новых строк в `DataTable` вызовите метод
   `TableAdapter.Update`. Можно контролировать объем данных для
   обновления путем передачи всего `DataSet`, `DataTable`, массива `DataRow`
   или одной `DataRow`.

*Для вставки новых записей в базу данных с помощью метода TableAdapter.Insert:*

1. Вызовите метод адаптера таблиц `Insert`, передав значения для каждого
   столбца в качестве параметров.

**Вставка новых записей с помощью командных объектов**

То есть новые записи будут вставляться непосредственно в базу данных с помощью командных объектов. То есть создать `SqlConnection`, открыть соединение, выполнить команду и закрыть. В принципе то, что Вы делаете уже у себя.

*Для вставки новых записей в базу данных с помощью командных объектов:*

1. Создайте новый командный объект, задав его свойства `Connection`,
   `CommandType` и `CommandText`.

**Примечание:**

> Необходимо иметь доступ к базе данных, к которой вы пытаетесь
>   подключиться, а также разрешение на вставку записей в нужную таблицу. Ну, думаю это и так понятно.

---

Касаемо подхода с `OleDbConnection`, конечно, на первый взгляд, он кажется неудобным и громоздким, но если все вынести в отдельные методы и красиво оформить, к примеру сделать универсальные методы для вставки, выборки и удаления объектов и вынести в отдельный класс, что-то на подобии Helper, то Вы не заметите той громоздкости, которая окутывает Вас сейчас, выглядит это не так уж и плохо. Думаю именно от этого и начинаются поиски других подходов.

Также, думаю, что будут полезны следующие ссылки:

1. [Общие сведения об адаптере таблиц](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bz9tthwx.aspx)
2. [Класс SqlCommand](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.aspx)
3. [Класс DataTable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.data.datatable.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Так как очевидные способы перечислены, то приведу альтернативы:

**microsoft dao 3.6 object**

Если важна скорость, то можно использовать библиотеку `microsoft dao 3.6 object library`.

Вот [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7070011/writing-large-number-of-records-bulk-insert-to-access-in-net-c) пруф скорости.

Я сам убедился на практике, что он быстрее.

Работа с ним похожа на ваш код, заисключеним того, что эта сборка `COM`=> нужно следить за закрытием соединений.

**Interop**

Можно так же работать с Access через Interop.

Работа будет похожа, на то, как если бы вы писали VBA модуль в Access, но на C#.

Этот способ дает еще больше возможностей, так как вы получаете доступ к объектам Access, например запросы и модули.

Например, вы можете выполнить модуль Access из кода C#.

Но опять же, нужно следить за объектами, так как это тот же COM...

Для работы на целевой машине должен стоять Office или Access Engine.

**Dapper**

Можно воспользоваться Micro ORM Dapper, которая работает с теми объектами, которые реализуют IDbConnection в том числе и OleDbConnection.

С ним код выглядит яснее и лаконичнее.